# KEEP ALIVE support for websocket library in lua

Tags: http, websocket, lua

What is a good websocket client library in lua with KEEP ALIVE support?

Comment: Have you looked into `luasocket`? (http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html) it has a `keepalive` setting under the `setoption` function parameters. Is that sufficient for you needs?

Comment: this does not seem like a websocket client.